# SELECT 3 tabelas diferentes usando DAPPER?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dapper

Primeiramente gostaria de dizer que sou iniciante em programação, e estou em desenvolvendo meu primeiro projeto. Usando a Tecnologia ASP.NET MVC.

Preciso fazer uma consulta em 3 tabelas diferentes sendo elas: Usuário, Pais e Estado com os seguintes campos

**Usuario:** UsuarioId, Nome, Email, Senha, DataCadastro, EstadoId

**Pais:** PaisId, Nome, Sigla

**Estado:** EstadoId, Nome, Sigla, PaisId

Como posso fazer isso utilizando o Dapper ?

Comment: Adicione o schema das tabelas e as relações entre elas para facilitar a analise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, é importante dizer que o Dapper funciona muito bem como um complemento ao Entity Framework. Usar apenas o Dapper na sua aplicação pode implicar em uma perda de produtividade, já que o Dapper não possui, por exemplo, carga preguiçosa, controle incremental de banco e geração dinâmica de SQL. Tudo fica a encargo do programador, que tem que escrever **todas** as sentenças de interface com o banco manualmente.

Para esta resposta, vou supor que você cogitará usar ambos. Não tem problema não usar, mas o desenvolvimento ficará mais trabalhoso e espero conseguir mostrar isso aqui.

Tendo isto em mente, podemos escrever um guia rápido para o Dapper.

## Usando com o Entity Framework

O Dapper é basicamente uma biblioteca que estende [`IDbConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). Começando um novo projeto com Entity Framework, usar o Dapper é bastante simples:

```cs
using Dapper;

private EntityFrameworkContext context = new EntityFrameworkContext();
...

db.Database.Connection.Query(); // Query já é um dos métodos do Dapper.
```

## Selecionando

Vou usar `Pais` para o exemplo.

#### Um País

```cs
var umPais = context.Database.Connection.Query<Pais>("select * from Paises where PaisId = @Id", new { Id = 1 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

#### Todos os Países

```cs
var todosOsPaises = context.Database.Connection.Paises.Query<List<Pais>>("select * from Paises");
```

#### Joins

Vou usar agora `Estado` e `Pais`:

```cs
var sql = @"select e.EstadoId, e.Nome, e.Sigla, e.PaisId, p.PaisId, p.Nome, p.Sigla
            from Estados e
            inner join Paises p on e.PaisId = p.PaisId";

var estadosEPaises = db.Database.Connection
                       .Query<Estado, Pais, Estado>(sql, 
                                                    (e, p) => {
                                                                  e.Pais = p;
                                                                  return e;
                                                    },
                                                    splitOn: "PaisId");
```

## Inserindo

```cs
var resultadosAfetados = db.Database.Connection.Execute("insert into Paises (Nome, Sigla) values (@Nome, @Sigla)", new { Nome = "Brasil", Sigla = "BR" });
```

Dá pra inserir vários:

```cs
var resultadosAfetados = db.Database.Connection.Execute("insert into Paises (Nome, Sigla) values (@Nome, @Sigla)", new[] { { Nome = "Brasil", Sigla = "BR" }, { Nome = "Portugal", Sigla = "PT" } });
```

## Atualizando

Mesma coisa:

```cs
var resultadosAfetados = db.Database.Connection.Execute("update Paises set Nome = @Nome where Sigla = @Sigla", new { Nome = "Brazil", Sigla = "BR" });
```

## Excluindo

Preciso colocar?

## Facilitando

Escrever métodos de inserção, exclusão, etc., pode ser **bem** tedioso, então a equipe do Dapper criou um método que faz não ser necessário escrever inserções e atualizações:

```cs
    using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

    public void Persistir(IDbConnection connection, Usuario usuario) 
    {
        if (usuario.UsuarioId == null) {
            SqlMapperExtensions.Insert(connection, usuario);
        }
        else {
            SqlMapperExtensions.Update(connection, usuario);
        }
    }
```

> Vi que existe um Dapper.EntityFramework no fonte do Dapper. Por que você não usa?

Porque ele contém apenas duas tipagens para trabalhar adequadamente com coordenadas geográficas e geométricas. Tem pouca utilidade nos exemplos que fazem parte da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta. No caso eu estou querendo evitar o EF por se tratar de um projeto pequeno, então  o que seria melhor, usar ADO puro com stored procedures ?

Comment: Mas o EF atende bem tanto projetos pequenos quanto grandes. Você pode modelar o domínio com o EF e depois trocar tudo para um repositório Dapper se sentir que é melhor assim, mas opinativamente falando, não acho uma boa.

Answer (score 2):

Se você só quer consultar os dados sem fazer algum tratamento das informações antes de retornar, acho que o melhor a fazer é usar o `inner join`, pois assim as informações das tabelas não ficam todas na memória até encerrar a consulta, e comparado a outros tipos de consulta, é a mais eficiente.

`select tab_1.field, tab_2.field, tab_3.field from tab_1 inner join tab_2 on tab_2.id = tab_1.id inner join tab_3 on tab_3.id = tab_2.id where ...`